# How can I send ajax request in loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loops

Hi I have a Php page with html and ajax request.

I am taking screenshot of that html data and saving thar screenshot on server using ajax, my problem is I need to send multiple screenshot of that page without reloading but html must be change as per records.

```
<?php
if(count($users) > 0)
{ ?>

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

HERE IS HTML MUST CHANGE AS PER USER, I CANT RELOAD
THE PAGE AGAIN AND AGAIN AS THIS IS A CRON JOB

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>



<script type='text/javascript'>
function screenshot(){
     html2canvas(document.getElementById('testing')).then(function(canvas) 
{
//document.body.appendChild(canvas);
     // Get base64URL
     var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 
'image/octet-stream');

     // AJAX request
     $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/savePNG.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {image: base64URL, user_id:"<?php echo $valuevb['user_id']; 
 ?>"},
        success: function(data){
           console.log('Upload successfully');
        }
     });
   });
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: create two function, 1 is taking screenshot and other send data using ajax, whenever capture screenshot then just call the funcions as per need.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra you means js function

Comment: <script>
    function screenshot(){
         html2canvas(document.getElementById('testing')).then(function(canvas) {
         var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
         sendajax(base64URL);
       });
     }
     function sendajax()
     {
         $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/savePNG.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {image: base64URL, user_id:"<?php echo $valuevb['user_id']; ?>"},
            success: function(data){
               console.log('Upl');
            }
         });     }
     </script>

Comment: I changed it like above but its just processing nothing happening

Comment: @arvindpundir  Can you please explain in detail what exactly you mean by "html must be change as per records" ?

Comment: hi Patrick, it means I have displayed google graphs there as per user performance, so these graphs changes for every user, this is a cron job page so it will hit once